# Use Poisson to calculate amount of events on time-point T

Tags: problem-solving, factorial, poissons-equation

A Poisson distribution is used to calculate the probability that $K$ events occur over time interval $\tau$, assuming a rate $\lambda$.

This is done with the following formula:

$ P = \frac{(\lambda\tau)^k}{k!}*e^{-\lambda\tau}$

This all nice and well. What I would like to know is, how many events have happened at time-point $\tau$, given a probability $P$. I started rearranging the formula and ended up here:

$ \frac{P}{e^{-\lambda\tau}}*k! = (\lambda\tau)^k$

Assuming the following values:
$ P = 0.8$
$ \lambda = 1.6 $
$ \tau = 15 $

The function would be:

$ \frac{0.8}{3.78*10^{-11}}*k! = 24^k $

$2.12*10^{10}*k! = 24^k$

**How would I go about finding $k$?**

The solution may be an approximation. As long as $ P \geq 0.8 $ the solution would satisfy.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be surprised to find out that there is no exact solution. The Poisson PMF is far from being surjective. For an approximate solution, there is a fairly brute force way. $9!$ is on the order of $10^5$ (useful to remember). After that each factor you multiply by will raise the order by about $1$. So you should expect your answer to be around $9+4=13$. If you actually calculate it, you find that this is a bit too small, while 14 is a bit too big.

Comment: More importantly however, you appear to have made algebra error somehow; you should be trying to solve $0.8=e^{-24} \frac{24^k}{k!}$. The $24^k$ does not mysteriously collapse into a constant.

Comment: I indeed made a mistake. I fixed it now. It would suffice if the P would become larger than $0.8$. I want to use this formula to estimate how many people arrive at the airport every 15 minutes, for multiple flights, so I would not like to do that manually.

Comment: OK. I actually highly doubt that Poisson(24) has a single point with that property; it is a relatively spread out distribution, not particularly concentrated around its mean. Would it be useful to know the smallest $x$ such that $P(X \geq x) \geq 0.8$, or the largest $x$ such that $P(X \leq x) \leq 0.8$? Either of these seem useful in an application (depends on the application of course). And of course both are guaranteed to exist.

Comment: You might also be interested the smallest $\Delta x$ such that $P(X \in [24-\Delta x,24+\Delta x]) \geq 0.8$. This can yet again be obtained. But I don't think there is a closed form for any of these three.

Comment: @Ian The smallest to be above 0.8 would be perfect I think. I hoped it could be solvable mathematically but I am starting to see it will be more of a programming issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: It is a programming issue but you can make a decent guess, which will speed up your program (perhaps only slightly, but still) and also give some intuitive insight.